# How to move UIView outside its SuperView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiscrollview, superview

So, I have a custom UIView inside a UIScrollView. I am able to detect the touches Events in the customUIView. I am trying to drag the UIView outside the UIScrollView onto a Canvas (UIView). However, when it gets out of bounds from the SrollView, it just hides behind it? How can I overcome this? Thanks guys!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you start dragging the view, [remove it from the superview](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/removeFromSuperview) that is the UIScrollView, and make it a subview of the app's Window, and [bring it to front](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/bringSubviewToFront%3a) (z-order-wise).

But first you need to calculate ([convert](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/convertRect%3atoView%3a)) the dragging view's frame with regards to the window, since the coordinates will be different after changing its superview.

Comment: Yep, thanks for your input. This is the direction I followed and was able to figure it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method [UIView removeFromSuperView];